# Failover for NodeJS rhea AMQP client

Tags: node.js, amqp, rhea

I want to implement the failover mechanism in my NodeJS rhea code similar to what Spring Boot does with JMS.

I am using an AMQP connection in NodeJS use [rhea](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rhea) in the following way:

```js
var container = require('rhea');
container.on('message', function (context) {
    console.log(context.message.body);
    context.connection.close();
});
container.once('sendable', function (context) {
    context.sender.send({body:'Hello World!'});
});
var connection = container.connect({'port':5672});
connection.open_receiver('examples');
connection.open_sender('examples');
```

I want to provide multiple connections at `container.connect(multipleconnections)` from which it will pick available connections instead of just `container.connect({'port':5672})`.

Comment: Yes, @JustinBertram I have implemented it as a master-slave with a shared file system. I have multiple instances of ActiveMQ running

Comment: Right now this is how I am implementing my message broker https://www.npmjs.com/package/rhea using rhea

Comment: Your question lacks details needed to really provide sufficient answers, please edit and expand on your setup and what you are trying to achieve and what you've tried which hasn't worked out.

Comment: @TimBish, I have updated my question with more inputs, kindly validate and provide an answer, please

Comment: The Spring Boot implementation is irrelevant as far as I can tell since it is using the OpenWire JMS client rather an rhea. The two clients are completely different. It's not clear to me why you've mentioned it here.

Comment: @JustinBertram I wanted to implement the failover mechanism in my NodeJS rhea code as Springboot is doing with JMS. That is why I have give an example of the implementation I want in NodejS, which is being implemented in Java straightforward

Comment: at least I want to provide multiple connections at  container.connect(multipleconnections) from which it will pick available connections instead of  container.connect({'port':5672})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some work to build your client code such that reconnect happens, rhea doesn't have the sort of failover processing support that clients like Qpid JMS or the Artemis Core JMS client do.

There is a reconnect [example](https://github.com/amqp/rhea/blob/master/examples/reconnect/client.js) in the Rhea source tree that you can use as a starting point to build that logic into your own application.